# How to set maximum number of posts allowed for any specific custom post type in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an image slider on my Wordpress home page, I have created one simple custom post type home_image_slider which only has 2 fields ie. image url & image title.

Now as I only want to show maximum 5 images on my home slider I want a simple solution using which I can limit **Admin** from adding more than 5 images or you can say 5 post to this custom post type (as I need to show only 5 images on slider it does not make sense to allow admin to add more than 5 posts).

Answer (score 2):

We can check this at the very beginning of `/wp-admin/post-new.php`:

```
add_action('load-post-new.php', 'limit_cpt_so_23862828' );

function limit_cpt_so_23862828()
{
    global $typenow;

    # Not our post type, bail out
    if( 'home_image_slider' !== $typenow )
        return;

    # Grab all our CPT, adjust the status as needed
    $total = get_posts( array( 
        'post_type' => 'home_image_slider', 
        'numberposts' => -1, 
        'post_status' => 'publish,future,draft' 
    ));

    # Condition match, block new post
    if( $total && count( $total ) >= 5 )
        wp_die(
            'Sorry, maximum number of posts reached', 
            'Maximum reached',  
            array( 
                'response' => 500, 
                'back_link' => true 
            )
        );  
}
```

Maybe you can allow draft posts and make sure you're only pulling 5 slides in the frontend setting `'numberposts' => 5` in your `WP_Query` or `get_posts`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually It doesn't make sense to limit custom post type and normally they don't do it.  Whatever If you like to limit slider post to 5,  using theme option page might be better approach. You can either try manually or use appropriate theme options frameworks like

[Options framework](https://wordpress.org/plugins/options-framework/)

[Official Documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages)

[ThemeForest Discussion](http://themeforest.net/forums/thread/wordpress-theme-options-portfolio/77829)

[Option Tree](https://wordpress.org/plugins/option-tree/)

[Redux](http://reduxframework.com/)